# python adding a negative sign to calculation result

Tags: python

First, I will warn you, I am new at this so please bear with me.  I created the following program (for a class, of course) and everything works except that the withdrawal calculation spits out a negative number when the value shouldn't be negative.  Can you guys see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

```
#define the main
def main():
    name=input('Enter the customer\'s name: ')
    account_id=input('Enter the account ID: ')
    code=input('Enter the transaction code:')
    previous_balance=float(input('Enter the previous balance: '))
    transaction_amount=float(input('Enter the transaction amount: '))

    if code == "w" or code == "W":
        process_withdrawal (transaction_amount, previous_balance)
    else:
        if code == "d" or code == "D":
            process_deposit (transaction_amount, previous_balance)
        else:
            process_invalid_transaction_code (previous_balance)

#define process withdrawal
def process_withdrawal (previous_balance, transaction_amount):
    if previous_balance >= transaction_amount:
        print('You have entered an invalid transaction amount')
        balance=previous_balance
        print_balance (balance)                

    else:
        balance=previous_balance-transaction_amount
        print_balance (balance)        

#define process deposit
def process_deposit (previous_balance, transaction_amount):
    balance=previous_balance+transaction_amount
    print_balance (balance)

#define invalid transaction code
def process_invalid_transaction_code (previous_balance):
    print('You have entered an invalid transaction code.')
    balance=previous_balance
    print_balance (balance)

#define print balance
def print_balance(balance):
    print('Your current balance is :', format(balance, '.2f'))

main()
```

Comment: `if code == "w" or code == "W"` is the same as `if code in ("w", "W")`. Meaning, if the code is in that tuple. Not necessarily related to your question, but it's a good trick to know

Comment: Could you please include some input/output? Like, what is the output when you enter a few specific values as input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `process_withdrawal` has the first argument as `transaction_amount` and the second as `previous_balance`, but the function declaration has `previous_balance` as the first argument and `transaction_amount` as the second.

Try this:

```
if code == "w" or code == "W":
  process_withdrawal(previous_balance, transaction_amount)
```

Comment: Incidentally, problems like this can be made less frequent if you use classes (not the school kind, the Python class).  If you defined an `Account` class, with `deposit` and `withdraw` methods (each taking an amount) and a `balance` data member, none of this would likely have happened.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the arguments backwards.

process_withdrawal (transaction_amount, previous_balance)

and

def process_withdrawal (previous_balance, transaction_amount):

Answer (score 0):

I think your if statement within `process withdrawl` should be

```
if previous_balance < transaction_amount:
```

Comment: i tried that originally and it was all messed up (i.e. it computed the invalid option and gave the error for the valid one).  i totally have no idea why.

Comment: check out the other answers. you got your arguments mixed up. once you change the arguments though, i believe you will have to change to `if previous_balance < transaction_amount:`